# Issues with preceding sibiling/parent/ancestor

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
<div class='productHolder'>   
    <a href="https://ap.com" class="tea-time-with-ap">
        <div class="aptime-8" dataInfo="name">Hammer</div>
        <div class="aptime-9" dataInfo="price">$980</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Note: there are over 20 productHolder classes on the same page.

I am able to get the price data, how can i used parent or preceding sibling to get the href.

I use the following code to get price:

```
rawPrice = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'$')]/text()")[counter].extract()
```

I've spent 2 hours trying to use preceding sibling, parent and even changing the code to use other values but, I run issues elsewhere.

Any help is appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you looking for something like:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

html = """
<div class='productHolder'>   
    <a href="https://ap.com" class="tea-time-with-ap">
        <div class="aptime-8" dataInfo="name">Hammer</div>
        <div class="aptime-9" dataInfo="price">$980</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
"""

root = etree.parse(StringIO(html), etree.HTMLParser())
print(root.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"$")]/../@href')[0])
```

Result:

```
https://ap.com
```

Of course you can easily build from this:

```
item = root.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"$")]')
print(item[0].text)
print(item[0].xpath('../@href')[0])
```

Result:

```
$980
https://ap.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I'd need both values the price and href. You're answer gave me an idea though, I'll report back :-)

Comment: In your question, you asked how to get the `href`, indicating you were already able to get the price - but I added a simple example anyway. Obviously, you can build from this endlessly, I'm assuming the piece you were missing was the `../` for the parent reference.